# Ruby how to find each value in hash greater than x?

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I am bit new to Ruby and had a problem with learning hashes. I have hash which contains months and days inside this month. And I need to print each one that has 31 days.

```
months = {
  "MAR" => 31,
  'APR' => 30,
  'MAY' => 31,
  'JUN' => 30
}
```

Comment: What happened to MAY? It must feel robbed.

Comment: Sorry, a little typo in months :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
months.select { |_month, days| days > 30 }
```

This former gives you all results that fit the criteria (`days > 30`).

Here are the docs:

- [`select`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select)

Once you've got the values you need, you can then print them to the console (or output however you'd like), e.g.

```
long_months = months.select { |_month, days| days > 30 }
long_months.each { |month, days| puts "#{month} has #{days} days" }
```

---

All that being said, assigning to a value before printing the result means two loops, whereas this can be achieved in one using a simple [`each`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/each):

```
months.each do |month, days|
  puts("#{month} has #{days} days") if days > 30
end
```

That'll be more efficient as there's less churn involved :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your last code is working and helped me a lot!

Comment: Great,  very glad I could help @Silka :) If you feel you've got what you needed here and the answer filled the brief, I'd be grateful if you'd click the tick to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Check `select` method with a block

```
months.select{|key, value| value > 30}
```

Comment: So like I said? :D

Comment: Exactly :) Didn't see the answer when clicked the link.